# Faster way to look up multiple columns of data than VLookup in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have a large data processing spreadsheet that looks up a component number and then loads the relevant columns into an array.  Currently I am using the VLookup function, which is a very slow function to use thousands of times in a loop.

My current code section:

```
Set drng = Sheets(Data).Range("D2:AS" & imax)

On Error Resume Next 
For i = 1 To 7 

    jmax = Sheets(ShtName(i)).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 3 To jmax

        Component= Sheets(ShtName(i)).Cells(j, 1).Value2

        DataVar(1) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 32, False) 
        DataVar(2) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 35, False) 
        DataVar(3) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 42, False) 
        DataVar(4) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 11, False) 
        DataVar(5) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 15, False) 
        DataVar(6) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 24, False) 
        DataVar(7) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 18, False) 
        DataVar(8) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 38, False) 
        DataVar(9) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 21, False) 
        DataVar(10) = Application.VLookup(Component, drng, 29, False)

     Next j
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
```

Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Filtering is typically slow as well and I don't know a real good way to interface with the columns after the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want multiple columns of information from the same row, and you know which columns have that information, all you have to do is find the row the data is on and then you can reference the cells directly.  You can use the Match function to determine the row.

See this code:

```
For i = 1 To 7 

    jmax = Sheets(ShtName(i)).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 3 To jmax 

        Component = Sheets(ShtName(i)).Cells(j, 1).Value2

        With Sheets(Quarter)
            ComponentRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(Component, .Range("D:D"), 0)
            DataVar(1) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 35).Value2 
            DataVar(2) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 38).Value2 
            DataVar(3) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 45).Value2 
            DataVar(4) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 14).Value2 
            DataVar(5) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 18).Value2 
            DataVar(6) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 27).Value2 
            DataVar(7) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 21).Value2 
            DataVar(8) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 41).Value2 
            DataVar(9) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 24).Value2 
            DataVar(10) = .Cells(ComponentRow, 32).Value2 
        End With

    Next j

Next i
```